# Как скрыть пустой подотчет в Jasper reports

Tags: jasperreports, report, jasperstudio

Необходимо скрыть подотчет, если он ничего не возвращает. Пробовал через jasper studio  ставить галочку remove line when blank не помогло. Так же в самом коде пытался изменить значения высоты band на 0, т.к. советывали на другом сайте. Не помогло. Вот код элемента с сабрепортом:

```
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{NotificationsEnabled}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="752" height="43" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8bc61874-9de5-4f10-b85a-fa6de25fc344">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="db_schema">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{db_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ProjectIds">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ProjectIds}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CustodianIds">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CustodianIds}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="NotificationIds">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{NotificationIds}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "LegalHoldNotificationOverview.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что тот, кто писал этот отчет до меня, добавил туда break'еры.